# How to solve $2x(4-x)^{\frac{-1}{2}}-3\sqrt{4-x}=0$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm struggling to figure out how to solve $2x(4-x)^{\frac{-1}{2}}-3\sqrt{4-x}=0$ for $x$.

The answer is $x = \frac{12}{5}$, but I am getting $x = \frac{-35}{9}$

**My steps are:**

$2x(4-x)^{\frac{-1}{2}}-3\sqrt{4-x}=0$

- make exponent postive

$2x\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 3\sqrt{4-x} = 0$

- square everything

$4x^2\frac{1}{4-x} - 9(4-x) =0$

- combine into one fraction

$\frac{1-9(4-x)[4x^2(4-x)]}{4x^2(4-x)} = 0$

- remove like terms

$1-9(4-x)=0$

$1-36-9x = 0$

$x = \frac{-35}{9}$

Comment: "square everything "  but you didn't.  $(a - b)^2 = a^2 -2ab + b^2 \ne a^2 - b^2$.  It would be better to do:  $a -b = 0 \implies a = b \implies a^2 = b^2$.  You can *NOT* $a-b = 0 \implies (a-b)^2 = 0 \implies a^2 - b^2 = 0$.  Two wrong might make a right.  But they are wrong when they do.

Comment: Besides fleablood's comment, you also somehow slipped $4x^2$ into the denominator and incorrectly canceled in the next step.  $\frac{a-b}c=\frac ac-\frac bc$.  The 1 should have been over the entire denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4-x}}-3\sqrt{4-x}=0$$

Then

$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4-x}}=\frac{3\sqrt{4-x}}{1}$$

If we cross multiply we get that

$$2x=3(4-x)=12-3x$$

You can go from here....

Comment: Thanks! This helps!

Answer (score 2):

This step is wrong

> square everything 
>   $4x^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 9(4-x) =0$

Once you square everything you get (i.e. $a=b$, then $a^2=b^2$, then $a^2-b^2=0$)
$$4x^2\frac{1}{4-x} - 9(4-x) =0$$
Now multiply by $(4-x)$, we get
$$4x^2 - 9(4-x)^2 =0$$
or
$$(2x)^2 - [3(4-x)]^2 =0$$
which gives 
$$(2x -12 + 3x)(2x +12 - 3x)=0$$
Finally we get
$$(5x -12 )(12 - x)=0$$
Obviously $12=x$ is not accepted, but $x = \frac{12}{5}$ is.

Answer (score 1):

If we put $x=4t$, the equation becomes

$$\frac{4t}{\sqrt{1-t}}=6\sqrt{1-t}$$

and
$$2t=3(1-t)$$
which gives
$$t=\frac 35 \; ,\; x=\frac{12}{5}.$$